# sending an email using localhost with MAMP

Tags: php, email, sendmail

so basically I am trying to send an email over local host and the program I am using is MAMP. I have looked this up online and done everything written however, this still won't work. My Apache port is set to : 8888 my SQL port is set to: 3306 The function I have entered as php file to send emails is the one below:

```
mail(
     $admin_email, $messaage,
     'Works!',
     'An email has been generated from your localhost, congratulations!');
```

furthermore, I have filled out all the send mail value as shown below:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=ssl
auth_username=my_email@gmail.com
auth_password=*******

hostname=localhost
```

Obviously - my email and password are filled out using my email and password. also i have altered the php.ini file as shown:

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = C:\Windows\System32\sendmail\ -t -i -f   my_email@gmail.com
```

Can someone tell me where my error is ? any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = don@tripleroi.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path =/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f  yourname@example.com
```

If you are use gmail then,

```
    'host' = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' = '465',
```

**Note**: you must be login while sending mail

Comment: what do you mean by login ?

Comment: when you send through email you must logged to this account.